# How to get private key with web3 v0.2.x?

Tags: web3js, private-key, cryptography, web3js-v1.x, web3js-v0.x

`web3` version 1.x has the `decrypt` method, which decrypts a keystore v3 JSON.

By using it the following way, I can get the private key easily:

```
web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(keystoreJsonV3, password);
```

But how to get the private key with `web3` version 0.2.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web3 v0.20.xx doesn't have such functionality. You can use a third party library like [Ethereumjs Wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).